# Handling EINTR (with goto?)

Tags: c++, goto, system-calls, eintr

**Background:** This is a follow-up question to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957759/using-gprof-with-sockets) about handling EINTR for system calls in C++ (Linux/GCC).  Regardless of whether or not I intend to profile my application, it seems like I should be handling system calls setting `errno` to `EINTR` as a special case.  There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451/goto-usage), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful), [many](http://xkcd.com/292/) opinions about the use of `goto`.

**My question:** is a system call setting `errno` to `EINTR` a case where `goto` is considered nominal?  If not, then how would you suggest converting the following code to handle `EINTR`?

```
if ( ( sock_fd = ::socket( domain, type, protocol ) ) < 0 ) {
  throw SocketException( "Socket::Socket() -> ::socket()", errno );
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Cheers,
-Chris

**UPDATE:** Based on the answers below, I wound up writing the following macro:

```
#define SOCK_SYSCALL_TRY(call,error)              \
  while ( (call) < 0 ) {                          \
    switch ( errno ) {                            \
      case EINTR:                                 \
        continue;                                 \
      default:                                    \
        throw SocketException( (error), errno );  \
    }                                             \
  }                                               \
```

Which is used to transform my original snippet to this example:

```
SOCK_SYSCALL_TRY( sock_fd = ::socket( domain, type, protocol ), "Socket::Socket() -> ::socket()" )
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Chris, get this book: http://www.unpbook.com - you'd be glad you did. The source code is online http://www.unpbook.com/src.html - see there for examples of how to handle EINTR.

Comment: I'd never thought to use while/continue - great ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know the socket system call can't return with errno set to EINTR.
For other cases I use a loop:

```
while ((::connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&destAddress, sizeof(struct sockaddr))) == -1) {
    if (errno == EINTR) {
        LOGERROR("connect interrupted, retry");
        continue;
    } else if (errno == EINPROGRESS) {
        break;
    } else {
        LOGERROR("connect failed, errno: " << errno);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I programed an FTP server and I never had to use goto. I usually constructed interruptable system-calls like this:

```
    while( (ret = 
        splice_stream( data, NULL, file, &block_offset, 
            XFER_BLOCK_SIZE )) == -1 )
    {
        switch( errno )
        {
        case EINTR:
            if( server_handle_signal() )
                return FTP_QUIT;
            else
                continue;
            break;
        case EPIPE:
        case ECONNRESET:
            return FTP_ABOR;
        default:
            log_fatal("Splice error: %m\n");
            return FTP_ERROR;
        }
    }
```

EINTR means your server has caught a signal, and it is most of the time important to handle that signal.

Comment: I don't think you are handling the signal right. After your return from your system call with -1 and EINTR, the signal_handler has already been asynchronously invoked. You need to handle the signal in signal_handler, or use a signal_fd.